# How to count a consonant + silent "e" in Python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to write a rule for the consonant + silent "e" syllable subtraction in English. However, my method is incredibly inefficient and uses each consonant individually in its own if-else statement. Anyone have a method where it checks all consonants at once?

```
def syllable_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    count = 0
    vowels = "aeiouy"
    consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
    if word[0] in vowels:
        count += 1
    for index in range(1, len(word)):
        if word[index] in vowels and word[index - 1] not in vowels:
            count += 1

    if word.endswith(consonants[15] + "e"):
        count -= 1
    else:
        if word.endswith(consonants[15] + "es"):
            count -= 1
    
# ... etc etc...

    if count == 0:
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: use regular expressions: `re.search` for example

Comment: @OrenIshShalom how would you implement that? You first start with "import re" but then what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to expand your example of `if word.endswith(consonants[15] + "e")` to check all consonants at once? If you're trying to say "if the word ends with any consonant + e", then do this in place of checking `consonants[15]`:

```
if any(word.endswith(consonant + "e") for consonant in consonants)
```

If additionally it should be "consonant + e **or es**", then:

```
if any(word.endswith(consonant + "e") or word.endswith(consonant + "es") for consonant in consonants)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code + explanations inside:

```
import re

# inside the [ ... ] you can choose any letter once
# the letter e outside the [ ... ] means it must be followed by an e
pattern = "[bdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]e"

words = ["letter", "orchestra", "person"]
count = [
    len(["match" for m in re.finditer(pattern, w)])
    for w in words
]
print(count)
```

Comment: You may want this pattern: `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]e`